# sqlite version in python virtual environment is pointing to the old version

Tags: python, sqlite, python-venv

I have created a python virtual environment and installed the latest version of django that requires sqlite3 version greater than 3.7

If I type the following:

```
[python3-RIGS-venv] [dino@alder RIGS]$ sqlite3 -version
```

after activating my venv I get:

```
3.36.0 2021-06-18 18:36:39   5c9a6c06871cb9fe42814af9c039eb6da5427a6ec28f187af7ebfb62eafa66e5
```

but if I run python:

```
[python3-RIGS-venv] [dino@alder RIGS]$ python
Python 3.6.8 (default, Nov 16 2020, 16:55:22) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

and then check the sqlite version I get:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.7.17'
>>>
```

meaning I cannot run the django server as the wrong version of sqlite3 is used. How can I force python in my venv to read the right 3.36.0 sqlite library?

Comment: `sqlite3.version` is the version of the Python sqlite3 package, not of the underlying sqlite3 library.

Comment: OK, I need to update the Python sqlite3 package or the django package will raise an error when I try to run a server. How do I update that?